# In Linux, top command sort by field "TIME+" using command line, iterations 1 time

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, top

When we run top command and If we type "T", it will sort based on the TIME+

I want to sort by "TIME+" in command line, using top -n 1

so that I can capture all the process in a file and analyse it one by one.

Note: It is CentOs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
top -n 1 -b | tail -n +7 | sort  -k 11Vb
```

- `top -n 1 -b` : -b to avoid highlighting chars
- `tail -n +7` : to skip the headers written by top
- `sort -k 11Vb` : sort by the 11.th field, skipping white spaces, in a "version" sort mode

Use `-k 11Vbr` to have reverse order.

Comment: Excellent works in Centos.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ top -o TIME+ -n 1 >top.out
```

The `-o` option is use to select which column to sort on, `-n 1` will make `top` only update once before exiting.

Comment: @JJoao `top` on both OpenBSD and Ubuntu has `-o`.

Comment: Kusalananda, you are right: after updating my debian top I also have `-o`!!

Comment: My server is Centos, It is not working in centos. My Desktop is ubuntu, so it works. I want it in Centos.

Comment: @Mani, I had a similar issue: the `top's` option `-o` was introduced "recently": in the next update of your server it will probably work fine. Centos and servers in general tent to be conservative.

Comment: @Mani CentOS 7.0 seems to also support the `-o` flag. Maybe it's time to upgrade? http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/top/